# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'string'

Tags: python, string, sorting

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'string'
```

So here is the code:

```
lnumber=input("please type in numbers:")
lnumber.string().sort()
print(lnumber)
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- user inputs numbers (e.g.: `'2 1 4 3'`); and
- the code puts the numbers in ascending order.

Comment: `input` returns a `str` object, which doesn't have a `string` method - what were you expecting to happen? For the list of methods that `str` objects *do* have, see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: @grc apologies, wrong link (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods); still no `str.string`, though.

Comment: what that weird string() applied to a string should do? maybe (if string is consistent) lst = [int(x) for x in lnumber.split(' ')];lst.sort()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is inputting numbers in that way then you probably want to use raw_input.  After that you can use .split() to get a list of the numbers and then use .sort().

Example:

```
myRawInput = raw_input("Enter some numbers separated by spaces")
myList = myRawInput.split()
myList.sort()
```